# Mixing a fixed PX siderbar with percentage based content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

trying to create a new layout but have run into an issue.

Currently, i have a fixed sidebar to the left and then the content floated right.

The side bar has a width of 18%, and then the other content 82% width.

This works fine, but it looks ugly and is unstable at larger screen sizes.

I wish to however to make a change, and make the sidebar a fixed width. This poses a problem then on the other content which i want to take up the rest of the room.

How can i have the content to the right, to still take up the rest of the room whilst keeping a fixed sidebar?

Hope this makes some sort of sense!

Here is a js fiddle of the problem i face:

http://jsfiddle.net/Uyv6w/

And what i current do:

http://jsfiddle.net/Uyv6w/1/

Layout is like so:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="inner"></div>
    </div
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for - but I tried with this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Uyv6w/2/).

I floated the major divs left, then just gave a min-width and max-width to the container.

Could you provide some more details?

CSS

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #333;
}
#container {
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 600px;
    max-width: 1200px;
}
#sidebar {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #9b59b6;
}
#content {
    float: left;
    width: 82%;
    background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;}
#inner {
    width: 80%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color: gray;
    height: 1000px;
    padding: 10px;
}
img {
  display: block;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 20px auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is what i am trying to emuluate: http://themetrust.com/demos/ink/?project=the-city-of-samba But i cannot seem to figure out how to make the content centered? So on this theme the blog post is always say 20px left margin. But i dont know how to make it centered because i cant give its container a fixed width in px?

Comment: I've moved the fiddle to a real page - http://www.thedentons.us/coding/fluidbarsos.html - and made some adjustments. This will get you started. Use the IE F12 tools to investigate the original page, and you can learn more details about how they styled it.